Run-time error '7': NoSuchElementError for id that exists
Receiving Run-time error '7': NoSuchElementError
Element not found for XPath=//*[@id='agreeDisclaimer']
Error screenshot:

Code line:
Set WD = New ChromeDriver

    With WD
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get "www.redactedwebsite.com"
    End With
    
    ...

    WD.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='agreeDisclaimer']").Click

Using chromedriver version 123.0.6312.122 with chrome version 124.0.6367.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)
HTML snippet screenshot:

The link is here - I'm trying to check off the "I agree" checkbox and select 2022 Preliminary.
https://sartcorsonline.com/CSR/PublicSnapshotReport?ClinicPKID=2000065&reportingYear=2022

is the website URI public and shareable? There are various possibilities to explore. Snippet tool for HTML inserts useful.

@QHarr I've added the URL to the question.

@QHarr Added a 150 bounty, if you've got some time to take a look!

if not answered by weekend will look. Have you tried F8 step through and or testing SwitchTo?

@QHarr Ah, SwitchTo was what I needed! Used SwitchToNextWindow and SwitchToDefaultContent, thanks!

I think that if SwitchTo was the correct answer, maybe @QHarr or OP should post an answer about it so ithe question could be closed and the answer eligible for bounty.

Did you tried the xpath just like "//[@id='agreeDisclaimer']"?

@Qharr If you want to post your response as an answer, I'll give you credit. If not, I'll post my solution.

@gembird The issue was focusing on the wrong window, I had to add some SwitchTos and that fixed it. Will work on posting an answer to close the topic.

go ahead and post. I suggested SwitchTo as looked like a modal and I could see a new associated document

Thanks to @Qharr for the suggestion. Since the buttons were on a floating screen that popped up on the link, I was able to utilize 'SwitchTo' to access the checkboxes:
Set WD = New ChromeDriver

With WD
    .Start "Chrome"
    .Get "www.redactedwebsite.com"
End With

...

WD.SwitchToNextWindow 'added to switch to the new window

WD.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='agreeDisclaimer']").Click

WD.SwitchToDefaultContent 'added to switch back to the main window

